# How to merge two arrays if they both don't have the same size DART?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a question, how to combine two lists if they both don't have the same size?

For example, I have

```
 final List<CoffeeShop> coffeeShop = <CoffeeShop>[
    CoffeeShop(mrId: 1, shopTitle: 'Strarbucks A'),
    CoffeeShop(mrId: 2, shopTitle: 'Dunkin doghnuts B'),
    CoffeeShop(mrId: 3, shopTitle: 'Subway B'),
    CoffeeShop(mrId: 4, shopTitle: 'MCCafe A'),
    CoffeeShop(mrId: 5, shopTitle: 'Coffee Shop B'),
  ];
```

The second List:

```
final List<CoffeeShopMenu> coffeeMenu = <CoffeeShopMenu>[
    CoffeeShopMenu(sid: 1, shopMenuTitle: 'Matcha'),
    CoffeeShopMenu(sid: 1, shopMenuTitle: 'Matcha'),
    CoffeeShopMenu(sid: 4, shopMenuTitle: 'Matcha'),
    CoffeeShopMenu(sid: 4, shopMenuTitle: 'pie'),
  ];
```

I need the output:

```
List <Coffee> unite = <UnitedCoffee>[
UnitedCoffe(shopMenuTitle: 'Matcha', shopTitle: 'Dunkin doghnuts B),
]
```

I did something like this when I tried to resolve this issue, but in that case both array should heve the same size and if something change in the first array, I should the same thing in the another.

```
  final List<Coffee> coffee = uniteCoffee(coffeeShop, coffeeMenu);
  
  print(coffee);
  print(coffee[1].menu.shopMenuTitle);
  print(coffee[1].shop.shopTitle);
}

List<Coffee> uniteCoffee(List<CoffeeShop> coffeeShop, List<CoffeeShopMenu> coffeeMenu){
  if(coffeeShop.length != coffeeShop.length) return [];
  
  List<Coffee> temp = <Coffee>[];
  
  for(int i = 0; i<coffeeShop.length; i++) {
    temp.add(Coffee(coffeeShop[i], coffeeMenu[i]));
  }
  
  return temp;
}
```

Also I have a question^ if I use a Future Provider how can I resolve this issue in that case?

Comment: They are suppose to match the ```mrId```?

Comment: Hi @NelsonThiago they don't supposed to have the common id, but I want to filtrate them based on the CoffeeShop models. So you are rught they should filtrate by 'mrId'

Comment: Then it would be better two loops, this way there will be no problem with size difference, but in this way you are doing it, you expect two equal arrays in size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example that will work only if the condition to unite the coffeeShop with coffeeMenu is the mrId, when you use a loop inside the other there will be not problem with array sizes.

```
List<Coffee> uniteCoffee(List<CoffeeShop> coffeeShopList, List<CoffeeShopMenu> coffeeMenuList){  
  List<Coffee> temp = <Coffee>[];
  
  for(CoffeeShop coffeeShop in coffeeShopList) {
    for(CoffeeShopMenu coffeeMenu in coffeeMenuList){
      if(coffeeShop.mrId == coffeeMenu.mrId) {
        temp.add(Coffee(coffeeShop[i], coffeeMenu[i]));
      }
    }
  }
  
  return temp;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you @NelsonThiago I wanted to ask in theory can I put this loop in Provider and get the acess to data or I sould use FutureBuilder? My concept is to have 2 screens where user taps on the first screen and go to the second there all items are filtered? Cause my API has the same models and both models don't have the common id. I used the '''where''' method and trying to filtrate but it dosen't work, so I decided to merge both models and get access. May be I think wrong

Comment: Yes, Provider would work, in theory, all you need is to get this data from api and filter on app starting or some user event like clicking a button, and once the data is loaded you would be able to display it with provider.